# When we use magnets in linear accelerators?

Tags: accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I'm searching particle accelerators. I couldn't see focusing magnets in Linear accelerators. When we need focusing magnets in Linacs? I'm sharing some photos of what ı found.[image]

Comment: You use them when you want to keep the beam together. In other words, all the time. Like-charged particles repel, and all beams have a divergence to constantly fight.

Answer (score 0):

there is a very good description on all the magnets used in linacs in the historical documentation on the SLAC at Stanford, which you can find on-line. If I can remember its address I will add it in an edit to this answer.

keeping that beam steered in the right direction and "in focus" was not as hard an undertaking as one might expect. At the (almost constant) speeds with which the electrons traversed the beam tube, its 10,000 foot length was foreshortened down to about 34 inches.

Comment: Link to online version of _The Stanford Two-Mile Accelerator_, "The Blue Book" https://www.slac.stanford.edu/library/2MileAccelerator/2mile.htm